# How to add new rows at top of the JTable and Change the color of newly inserted rows in Java?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jtable, netbeans-8

I am working on project in which in one module I have to show the data in a data grid (for which I am using JTable). The problem is that, when I insert the Data in JTable, it gets populated at the bottom of the table, and I want to show the new rows at the top of the table. Please guide me to achieve this task, any help will be appreciated. I am using NetBeans for the development.

Here is my code to populate the data:

```
  public void run() { 
    try { 
          FileWriter out = new FileWriter("test.txt");
          BufferedWriter bufWriter = new BufferedWriter(out);

              int nb = input.readInt();
          System.out.println("Read Length"+ nb);
          byte[] digit = new byte[nb];
          System.out.println("Writing.......");
          for(int i = 0; i < nb; i++)
            digit[i] = input.readByte();

           String st = new String(digit);
          bufWriter.append(st);
           bufWriter.close();
           out.close();
            System.out.println ("receive from : " + 
            clientSocket.getInetAddress() + ":" +
            clientSocket.getPort() + " message - " + st);

                           DefaultTableModel table = (DefaultTableModel)_table.getModel();
            File file = new File("test.txt");
            Scanner f = new Scanner(file);
            String line = null;
            String[] str = null;

            while(f.hasNext()){
                line = f.nextLine().replace('|', ',');
                str = line.split(",");
                                    table.addRow(str);
                                    _table.setBackground(Color.red);


            }


          output.writeInt(st.length());
          output.writeBytes(st); 
        } 
        catch(EOFException e) {
        System.out.println("EOF:"+e.getMessage()); } 
        catch(IOException e) {
        System.out.println("IO:"+e.getMessage());}  

        finally { 
          try { 
              clientSocket.close();
          }
          catch (IOException e){/*close failed*/}
        }
    }
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You may wish to consider using your own `TableModel` rather than using the default one.

Comment: Okay let me check the tutorial for that.

Answer (score 3):

> The problem is that, when I insert the Data in JTable, it gets populated at the bottom of the table, and I want to show the new rows at the top of the table

```
table.addRow(str);
```

Well actually you are not inserting a row, you are adding a row. Try reading the `DefaultTableModel` API for a method that will allow you to "insert" a row at a specified location in the model, which in your case would be row 0.

Comment: Thank you so much, I just used `insertRow()` to populate the data, it worked perfectly. Please help me in changing the color of the newly inserted rows, this is the last thing I have to do and I don't have much time.

Comment: @MDaimKhan, glad it helped. Don't forget to "accept" the question so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: `Please help me in changing the color of the newly inserted rows`  - that requirement doesn't make sense. Why do newly inserted row need a separate color. What happens if you press the button twice to insert rows? Does each insertion group get a different color? Does the previous group get reset? Not enough information to provide an answer. Create a separate question with more details. Only one question per posting should be asked. `I don't have much time` - that is irrelevant to the question. Time management is your problem. Your question has no more priority than any other question.

Comment: `What happens if you press the button twice to insert rows?` Data is not populating on Button click, it will get populated once in a day. `Does each insertion group get a different color?` No `Does the previous group get reset?` Yes the color will get reset to its default.  `Not enough information to provide an answer.` how much information you need to answer a simple question that I just have to change the color of newly inserted rows? `Only one question per posting should be asked.` Yes I agree its my mistake thanks for the suggestion.